# csp allow sites to embed an iframe from our site

Tags: apache, tomcat, content-security-policy

Our apache front end always adds a CSP header with frame-ancestor that basically whitelists only our domain. However, I have one page that I would like any site to be able to put into an iframe. I dont want to be whitelisting everyone that wants it. Is there a way to set up csp header to allow this?

Comment: Put `frame-ancestors *` into the policy. Or in the off chance that you happen to already have a liberal `defaut-src` policy — e.g, `default-src *` — or if you have no `default-src` at all, then you could just omit the `frame-ancestors` directive altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for a specific page, you can set the CSP header Security at a page level, but you have to use `meta tags in the HTML`. Just provide specific directives at page level using HTML meta tags. Here’s an example that sets the same policy as above:

```
//modify source as needed
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```